# $p(\sin x) = \sin(2x)?$

Tags: trigonometry

a) Are there polynomials $ p (x) $ satisfying 
$ p(\sin x) = \sin (2x) \quad\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $ ?

b) An extension of this problem is:

1) If $n$ is even, then there does not exist a polynomial $P$ satisfying $P\left(\sin x\right)=\sin\left(nx\right)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

2) If $n$ is odd, then there exists a polynomial $P$ satisfying $P\left(\sin x\right)=\sin\left(nx\right)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

3) There exists a polynomial $P$ satisfying $P\left(\cos x\right)=\cos\left(nx\right)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

For the non-existence in 1) (and also for a) point) we can simply note that $\sin x=\sin (\pi-x)$ and hence $P(\sin x)=P(\sin (\pi-x))$ but $\sin(n(\pi-x))=-\sin nx$ for even $n$. Contradiction.

But I can’t solve point 2) and 3) can somebody help me?

Comment: Hint: [De Moivre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) together with $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Comment: For point 1: you're right, but there exists a polynomial $P$, of degree $n-1$, such that $\;\sin nx=\cos x\,P(\sin x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily construct an example for 3).

Take $P(x)=2x^2-1$. Then, $P(\cos x)=2\cos^2x-1=\cos2x$

For 2), You can take $P(x)=3x-4x^3$. So, $P(\sin x)=3\sin x-4\sin^3x=\sin3x$

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition).